# Difference between completion variables and semaphores

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel, semaphores are used to provide mutual exclusion for critical sections of data and Completion variables are used to synchronize between 2 threads waiting on an event. Why not use semaphores for such a synchronization ? Is there any advantage of using a completion variable over a semaphore ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two reasons you might want to use a completion instead of a semaphore.  First, multiple threads can wait for a completion, and they can all be released with one call to `complete_all()`.  It's more complex to have a semaphore wake up an unknown number of threads.

Second, if the waiting thread is going to deallocate the synchronization object, there is a race condition if you're using semaphores.  That is, the waiter might get woken up and deallocate the object before the waking thread is done with `up()`.  This race doesn't exist for completions.   (See Lasse's post.)

Answer (score 14):

Explanation of why completions were originally implemented:
http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0107.3/0674.html

> The basic summary is that we had this
>   (fairly common) way of waiting for
>   certain events by having a locked
>   semaphore on the stack of the waiter,
>   and then having the waiter do a
>   "down()" which caused it to block
>   until the thing it was waiting for did
>   an "up()".
>
> This works fairly well, *but* it has a
>   really small (and quite unlikely) race
>   on SMP, that is not so much a race of
>   the idea itself, as of the
>   implementation of the semaphores. We
>   could have fixed the semaphores, but
>   there were a few reasons not to:
>
> - the semaphores are optimized (on purpose) for the non-contention case. 
>     The "wait for completion" usage has
>     the opposite default case
> - the semaphores are quite involved and architecture-specific, exactly
>     due to this optimization. Trying to
>     change them is painful as hell.
>
> So instead, I introduced the notion of
>   "wait for completion":

More recent thread about completions vs semaphores
http://lkml.org/lkml/2008/4/11/323

Comment: It should be noted that a POSIX conformant semaphore implementation avoids the race the Linux kernel semaphores have for this usage case, and it can be made just as optimal as long as you have an atomic compare-and-swap operation. See my questions on the topic and the solution that was arrived at.

Comment: @R.. do you mind linking me to solutions you commented above please?